# Objects not visible in other frames/window but all the objects are in the library

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I'm doing a project and I mainly work with one window. (Correct me if I'm not using these terms correctly.) When I open a new window, half the objects disappear, but they're still in the library and the eye thing is selected to tell me it's visible, so the objects are still there?

I've tried rendering out the image and it has the same effect, half of the objects are not there. All the objects are still visible in the original window I was making them in, and I can edit and do whatever I wish with it as if it were normal. I'm using cycles render and that's basically all I know.

Comment: Are you in local view?

Comment: Can you provide screen shots?

Answer (score 2):

See if your objects are in different layers, and what layers are visible in those new windows.